# Eclipse: svn:externals in cross-platform Phonegap folder structure?

Tags: android, eclipse, svn, cordova

In Eclipse (on Windows) I created a cross-platform folder structure for Phonegap :

```
--phonegap_android 
   --assets
     --www         (symlink/junction to 'src')
       ...
--phonegap_ios   
    ...
--src
    index.html
```

Here's what I did to get this working :

- created an Android-project in Eclipse based on the `phonegap-android`
  folder.
- made a junction for the '`assets/www`' folder to link with '`src`' (using the Sysinternals command)
- created a svn-repository, for this entire project (the parent project that has the different folders for android, ios and src).

I can run the application now, but I have problems committing the project to svn.

The '`www`' folder is a junction-folder, so when changes are made to this folder, I want this folder to commit to the *real* source folder : '`src`'.

I tried different approaches :

- Setting an svn:ignore on '`assets`' to ignore '`www`', but then of course
  *nothing* in `www` is committed, when I commit the android-project in Eclipse.
- Setting an svn:externals on '`assets`' to define '`www`' as an
  external to `svn://myproject/src`, but then it still tries to commit everything in `assets/www` and I get an error 'No versioned parent directories'.

Any ideas how to get the `www` folder NOT committed, but at the same time get the `src` folder to get committed to the svn repository?

Answer (score 1):

Dylan,

Following with svn:externals will work.

- Create Folder 'phonegap_android'
- Under 'phonegap_android' create folder 'assets'
- Commit them to svn repository 'svn://myproject/phonegap_android'
- Now for the 'phonegap_android' folder, set the svn:externals as follow

  - '../src assets/www'(if your svn path for src is at same level as phonegap-android svn://myproject/src which is in your case)
- On windows using tortoise svn, it will let you commit 'phonegap_android' folder with svn:external changes.
- Take svn updates and you are done.

Henceforth whatever you commit to phonegap_android/asset/www folder, it will be committed to src folder(svn://myproject/src)